# XHR request uses local storage to construct the endpoint giving 400 in cypress.io

Tags: javascript, rest, automated-tests, integration-testing, cypress

I have an API request that gets triggered on checking a checkbox in my application which gives 200 status code when I run locally (localhost) but when I run the same using cypress, the response is giving 400.

**Cy based - BDD Definition:**
[image]

**Error:**
[image]
[image]

**Application Behaviour:**
The application fetches a value from local storage to construct that endpoint and while using cypress, it does not seem fetching from local storage even though the local storage has the value, and that is why it is giving 400.

Usual endpoint structure:
`http://localhost:8000/wms/api/v1/kml/F20210422060000/Wind50M?view=grid`

Usual endpoint structure when local storage is empty/has issue:
`http://localhost:8000/wms/api/v1/kml/F00000000000000/Wind50M?view=grid`

Cypress endpoint structure:
`http://localhost:8000/wms/api/v1/kml/F00000000000000/Wind50M?view=grid`

I have tried giving wait up to 15 seconds, refreshed the URL, but none seem to be able to solve this issue. so some ideas to make it work would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is  `F20210422060000`? is that an Id of something ?

Comment: It is a forecast ID, starts with F followed by timestamp value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is due to application behaviour and has nothing to do with Cypress. Of course, it is very difficult to determine from where the issue occurs but I stumbled across the solution after giving a static wait for some other tests.

Answer (score 0):

> Aliases are reset before each test

https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/variables-and-aliases#Aliases-are-reset-before-each-test

Can you setup your intercept in a before/beforeEach?
Sorry I am not versed in Cucumber with Cypress.

Comment: Thank you, intercept rightly captures and the alias is set correctly  (as you can see it returns 400 status code), also the complete scenario in cucumber is considered as a test. The challenge is, it is not hitting the right end point only thru cypress?

Comment: I see, thanks for the info about cucumber. It sounds to me like maybe there is something wrong with the localStorage access. Maybe this will help? https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-localstorage-commands